# Is 'Get' necessary in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) sometimes gets used as a synonym or shorthand for Active Directory® itself.

Question: Is "Gets" usage in this sentence correct? Can we omit 'Gets' and rephrase as below?

> LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) sometimes used as a synonym or shorthand for Active Directory® itself

Comment: No.  I'm not sure on the exact terminology to make this a proper answer, but you need either "sometimes gets used" or "is sometimes used".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot omit **gets** because then the sentence would have no main verb.

This sentence is an example of the passive voice, specifically the [*get-passive*](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/the-passive-voice-with-get-/4839624.html).  The get-passive is used with the verb **to get** and a past participle: get married, get called, get elected, etc.  In this case, "LDAP" is getting used *by someone else* as a synonym.

If you omit **gets**, it's not a passive construction anymore and looks like an active construction, like "Sarah **used** the screwdriver to open the box."  But then **as a synonym** doesn't make any sense, because the beginning of the sentence is saying that LDAP itself was using something else.

---

**Get** is also a very informal way of saying this, and overuse of **get** is a hallmark of English learners.  In this case, [**is used as a** is much, much more common than **gets used as a**.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gets%20used%20as%20a%2Cis%20used%20as%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgets%20used%20as%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20used%20as%20a%3B%2Cc0)